# How to get an image file from a static path?

Tags: javascript, angular, file

I have a JSON

```
MyJson = {name:"file1",path:"d://photos/photo.jpg"}
```

I want to get photo.jpg in a const variable

```
const file: File = MyJson.path;
```

How can I do this using Angular or Javascript?
This is not a duplicate of [How to read text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) please don't close.
I want to read this file as dataUrl.

Comment: Why this question is closed? I already tried the solution given in the link. It works for text files, not for image files. I want to read an image file.

Comment: It's not the best duplicate target, but it does apply (particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28610354/157247)) **if** you can do it at all. But you probably can't do it at all. If you're doing this from a page loaded via `http:` or `https:`, you **cannot** read local files with paths you specific in your code, for obvious security reasons. The user has to provide the file to you (via an `input type="file"` or drag-and-drop, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer T.J. I wanted some answer rather than downvote or duplicate.I will try to find other way

Comment: There's no point in people writing duplicate answers to duplicate questions. The answers already exist. They aren't going to change just because you don't like them. JavaScript can't give the browser a file path to a file on the user's computer and have it read it into the website — that would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping the newbie guys. I am learning. :)